# Do ReLU1 in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to use ReLU1 non-linear activation. ***ReLU1 is linear in [0,1] but clamps values less than 0 to 0 and clamps values more than 1 to 1***.

It will be used only for the last layer of my deep net in PyTorch having a really high definition output of `2048x4096`. Since the code has to be highly optimized in terms of speed and memory I do not know which of the following will be the best implementation.

Following are the two implementations I can think of for the tensor `x`:-

`x.clamp_(min=0.0, max=1.0)`
For this I am unable to see the source code given in its [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.3.1/torch.html#torch.clamp). So do not know if its the best choice. I will prefer in place operation since backpropagation can happen through it.

The second alternative I have is to use `torch.nn.functional.hardtanh_(x, min_val=0.0, max_val=1.0)`. This is definitely a in place function and the source code says that it uses the C++ file `torch._C._nn.hardtanh(input, min_val, max_val)` so I think it will be fast.

Please suggest which is the most efficient implementation and another one if possible.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying it, my guess is that `clamp` and `hardtanh` will have the same speed, and it will be hard to do this operation any faster if you optimize it in isolation. The arithmetic is trivial so this operation will be bottlenecked by GPU memory bandwidth. To run faster, you'd want to fuse this operation with the operation that produced `x`. If you don't want to write a custom kernel for the combined operation, you can try using [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html).

Comment: in many codes I see a lot of people use the functional form `nn.functional.relu`, `nn.functional.pixelshuffle`, instead of the much more recommended `nn.ReLU`, etc. I think they do it for speed up as the module caller is simply calling the functional form in their forward definition. So I though the above two posted in question will also have some performance differences.

Comment: That seems like it will cause a few microseconds of Python overhead on the CPU, but it won't matter at all because the CPU is always running ahead of the GPU (launching CUDA kernels asynchronously) and the GPU will be the bottleneck.